# ATG Repository API

Tags: java, repository, atg

Im trying to update multiple records via an ATG class extending GenericService. 
However im running against a roadblock. 
How do I do a multiple insert query where i can keep adding all the items / rows into the cached object and then do a single command sync with the table using item.add()  ?

Sample code

the first part is to clear out the rows in the table before insertion happens (mighty helpful if anyone knows of a way to clear all rows in a table without having to loop through and delete one by one).

```
    MutableRepository repo = (MutableRepository) feedRepository;
    RepositoryView view = null; 

    try{
        view = getFeedRepository().getView(getFeedRepositoryFeedDataDescriptorName());
        RepositoryItem[] items = null;
        if(view != null){        
            QueryBuilder qb = view.getQueryBuilder();
            Query getFeedsQuery = qb.createUnconstrainedQuery();
            items = view.executeQuery(getFeedsQuery);
        }
        if(items != null && items.length>0){
            // remove all items in the repository
            for(RepositoryItem item :items){
                repo.removeItem(item.getRepositoryId(), getFeedRepositoryFeedDataDescriptorName());
            }
        }



        for(RSSFeedObject rfo : feedEntries){
            MutableRepositoryItem feedItem = repo.createItem(getFeedRepositoryFeedDataDescriptorName());

            feedItem.setPropertyValue(DB_COL_AUTHOR, rfo.getAuthor());
            feedItem.setPropertyValue(DB_COL_FEEDURL, rfo.getFeedUrl());
            feedItem.setPropertyValue(DB_COL_TITLE, rfo.getTitle());
            feedItem.setPropertyValue(DB_COL_FEEDURL, rfo.getPublishedDate());

            RepositoryItem item = repo.addItem(feedItem) ;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

The way I interpret your question is that you want to add multiple repository items to your repository but you want to do it fairly efficiently at a database level. I suggest you make use of the [Java Transaction API as recommended in the ATG documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23507_01/Platform.20073/RepositoryGuide/html/s0502repositoriesandtransactions01.html), like so:

```
TransactionManager tm = ...
TransactionDemarcation td = new TransactionDemarcation ();
try {
  try {
    td.begin (tm);

    ... do repository item work ...
  }
  finally {
    td.end ();
  }
}
catch (TransactionDemarcationException exc) {
  ... handle the exception ...
}
```

Assuming you are using a SQL repository in your example, the SQL INSERT statements will be issued after each call to `addItem` but will not be committed until/if the transaction completes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

ATG does not provide support for deleting multiple records in a single SQL statement.  You can use transactions, as @chrisjleu suggests, but there is no way to do the equivalent of a `DELETE WHERE ID IN {"1", "2", ...}`.  Your code looks correct.

It is possible to invoke stored procedures or execute custom SQL through an ATG Repository, but that isn't generally recommended for portability/maintenance reasons.  If you did that, you would also need to flush the appropriate portions of the item/query caches manually.